# Embedded Webservice exposed in my DLL

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have created a WebService for a program that I wrote. The Webservice is used to transfer License Settings, Version update information, and Report Errors. I have referenced this webservice as part of my project and everything works perfect. My Problem is when I reference the DLL I created in another Project I'm able to see/reference/and call the webservice functions/subs from the external program. How can I make the WebService invisible to people who reference my DLL?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer...

To make the web service reference internal:

1. In Solution Explorer, click the Show All Files icon.
2. In the Service References folder, expand the service reference. 
   You should see four icons.
3. Expand the Reference.svcmap icon.
4. Open the Reference.cs file.
5. Find and replace instances of "public" with "internal" in the following signatures. Supposing your WSDL file is named "foo":

   public interface fooPortType // becomes internal interface fooPortType
   public interface fooPortTypeChannel // becomes internal interface fooPortTypeChannel
   public partial class fooClient  // becomes internal partial class fooClient

There may be other types that need to be hidden, but those are the main parts.

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7015a11-9820-4d53-bb97-73c66e4d50b6/how-to-make-web-reference-non-public-ie-private?forum=asmxandxml

Comment: While this method does stop exposing the web service reference, it also stop my own program from being about to call the methods now as they error with "XXX Web Service method name is not valid."